# What's the difference between "afraid of", "afraid from", "afraid for" and "afraid at"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

I need an explanation of the difference between these ways of using "afraid" in sentences and also a short definition that is easy to understand. And how to use each one in sentences.

1. She was so **afraid of** getting in trouble.
2. I am not **afraid from** my home.
3. I'm **afraid for** you, Mother.
4. And if you feel **afraid at** any moment, you can...

Comment: (2) doesn't make sense, but the other three show that you know how to use the word in sentences. You are _afraid of_ something frightening and _afraid for_ someone who may be in danger. _At any moment_ is a phrase, so _at_ doesn't belong with _afraid_.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, afraid is being used to express anxiety or trepidation over a future possibility.

The second sentence, afraid is being used to express a lack of fear regarding an object or place.

In the third sentence, afraid is being used to express similar feelings em-pathetically, to show concern for another.

In the fourth sentence, afraid is being used as a benchmark to indicate a response, meaning that if the subject of the sentence was to develop such a feeling they should or could undertake an action.